# Advanced loop problems for python

Tags: python, loops

I have been learning python through a book called "Introduction to Computer Science Using Python and Pygame". In this book there is a section called advanced loop problems with no explanation or overview on how to do them, but I thought i would attempt them anyway. I have the first 2 of them down thanks to some help from here, and here are the rest:

[image: Probs 1-3]
[image: Probs 4-6]

Here is the code for the first 2 problems, and my attempt at the third. Any help on the rest of these would be greatly appreciated!

```
#Problem 1:
for n in range(10):
    for i in range(10):
        print(i, end=" ")
    print()

#Problem 2:
for n in range(11):
    for i in range(n):
        print(i, end=" ")
    print()

#Problem 3:
for n in reversed(range(10)):
    for s in reversed(range(10)):
        print(" ", end="")
    for i in range(n+1):
        print(i, end=" ")
    print()
```

Comment: We won't do your homework :) Take a look at Python's "mini string formatting language" and `**` (power of) for the third one. For the other ones you need to add some spaces using `' ' * 5` and combine that with your working examples.

Comment: It's not for an actual class, I've been trying to learn python with the SoloLearn app and this pdf book because it included pygame. I can find the link where I found the pdf for you if you'd like. Also, I tried the ** operator in my problem 3 by including it in the "for s in reversed(range(10)): part, but this only seems to make more spaces rather than stagger them downwards. Is there a resource you could link me that explains nested loops better than this book?

Comment: The issue isn't that it is for an actual class. Homework questions [*may or may not*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) be [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). This is not really a good fit for the StackOverflow format. Check [help] and [ask]

Comment: Oh okay... so it's kind of hard to understand but from the help center and how to ask it looks like i should ask each one of these six individually with a title that actually describes the question?

Comment: Or do i just need to add the description of the difficulty like it specifies in the model?

Comment: Try to think of these patterns like a chessboard. Maybe put the origin in the middle and calculate all other indices relative to that

Answer (score 1):

For problem 3, you got the hint that 2 inner loops were required, one for the spaces, one for the digits.

You need one space more for each line starting with 0 (looks like the line index), and one digit less starting with 10 (10 - line_index). Code can be:

```
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(i):
        print(' ', end=' ')
    for j in range(10-i):
        print(j, end=' ')
    print()
```

For problem 4, a hint is to use `":2d".format(n)` to ensure alignment

Answer (score 0):

This is for the third problem.
Further problems have similar solutions, just a little bit more tricky.
Spend as much time as it needs to get them done, it's worth your while and you will find yourself more advanced in python scripting :) Good luck

```
num_list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

for x in range(0,len(num_list)):
    print num_list

    for i in range(0,len(num_list)):
        if i <= x:
            num_list[i] = ' '
        else:
            num_list[i] = num_list[i] - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n= int(input("Enter a no"))
r= (n*2)-2
for i in range(1, n+1):
    print (" "*r, end=" ")
    r-=2
    k=i-1
    for j in range(1, i+1):
        print (j, end=" ")
    for j in range(k, 0, -1):
        print (j, end=" ")
    print (" ")
```

This is my answer for 5.

Answer (score 0):

Nabbish answers, but it was perfect loop practice:

```
#Problem 1

for row in range(0, 10):
    for num in range(0,10):
        print(num, end=" ")
    print()

#Problem 2

for row in range(0, 10):
    for num in range(0, row+1):
        print(num, end=" ")
    print()

#Problem 3

for row in range(0, 10):
    for space in range(0, row):
        print(" ", end=" ")
    for num in range(0, 10-row):
        print(num, end=' ')
    print()


# #Problem 4

# Option 1 - not so good
for row in range(0, 10):
    for column in range(0, 10):
        a = str(row*column).center(2)
        print(a, end=" ")
    print()

#Option 2 - perfect
for row in range(0, 10):
    for column in range(0, 10):
        print("{:2d}".format(row*column), end=" ")
    print()

#Problem 5

for row in range(1, 10):
    for space in range(9, row, -1):
        print(" ",end=" ")
    for num in range(1, row):
        print(num, end=" ")
    for num2 in range(row, 0, -1):
        print(num2, end=" ")
    print()

#Problem 6


for row in range(1, 10):
    for space in range(9, row, -1):
        print(" ",end=" ")
    for num in range(1, row):
        print(num, end=" ")
    for num2 in range(row, 0, -1):
        print(num2, end=" ")
    print()

for row in range(1, 9):
    for space in range(0, row):
        print(" ",end=" ")
    for num in range(1, 10-row):
        print(num, end=" ")
    print()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.